# Visiting an Azure Website while Publishing displays IIS Errors

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an MVC app hosted on an Azure Website.

I have custom errors enabled and working (when not publishing):

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/NotFound" xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="403" />
</customErrors>
```

When I publish the website from Visual Studio, if I try to visit the site while the dlls are being updated, I get a nasty IIS error.

I'm surprised that Azure doesn't wait to "tie down" the new version until the publication is complete, to avoid this scenario.  Is there a way to achieve this "instantaneous switch" behavior?

And/Or - How can I prevent this error from being displayed?

Comment: What the message showed in the "nasty iis error"?

Comment: @Fabrizio - dlls missing, it changes from one refresh to the next while publishing.  This tells me that high-availability and Azure Websites don't mesh well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say this would be unusual.  Depending on size of the deployment it may take a while for IIS to restart and reload leading to 503 Service Unavailable or similar errors in the meantime. CustomErrors won't help you here as the ASP.Net pipeline isn't even being reached at this point.  What Azure Website level are you running on (Free, Shared or Standard?)  If you can up the size of the instance to try and get things moving again more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you deployment is too slow. IIS detects changes in dll files and restart the app-pool automatically without waiting for the other dll files.
Try to set custom values in waitChangeNotification and maxWaitChangeNotification in web.config. Doing so you can ask IIS to wait for some seconds before restarting app-pool. I'm not sure if it works on Azure. On my on-premises IIS I use custom values that allow me to do a long deploy (about 5 seconds).
Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx